# Mui Drawer removes the application page content

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, sidebar, drawer

I've got a problem about mui Drawers. As I see on the internet, drawer never removes the content of the page, but in my case yes it does :( Can you help me to figure out what is the problem?

here is my Drawer component code:

```
import Drawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import  { useState }  from 'react';

import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

export default function SideBar() {
    const [isDrawerOpen, setDrawerOpen] = useState(false);
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setDrawerOpen(true)}>left</button>
            <Drawer
            anchor="right"
            open={isDrawerOpen}
            onClose={() => setDrawerOpen(false)}
            >
                <Box>sdfsd</Box>
            </Drawer>
        </div>
    
    )
    
   ;
}
```

And I call it on this page.

```
import Drawer from "../components/SideBar"

export default function ShopSingle(){
        <div>
            {/* <Navbar></Navbar>
            <HeaderHome></HeaderHome> */}
                <div>

                PAGE CONTENT
                <Drawer></Drawer>
                </div>

            
            {/* <Footer></Footer> */}
             </div>
}
```

I'm pretty new with React, can you help me the solve problem?

Comment: It is very likely a css problem. Can you provide a little sandbox that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should be add this line if you want drawer open in right side and your project is rtl:

```
sx={{
    '& .MuiDrawer-paperAnchorLeft': {
        right: '0 !important',
        left: 'unset !important',
        minWidth: '195px'
    }
}}
```